# ejabberd API invite to MUC room

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-auth

I am working on ejabberd API to invite users to MUC room. I have setup OAuth for API.

I have tested oauth with get_room_occupants and its working fine.

Now, I am trying to access `/api/send_direct_invitation`, but as per logs, I don't have permission to access this api

I have generated oauth with command line 
`ejabberdctl oauth_issue_token admin@host 31540000 "ejabberd:admin"`

Do I need to pass any extra permissions

**Ejabberd Version:** `17.11`
**Installed on:** `ubuntu 16.04` 
**Configuered DB:** `mysql`

Here is a `ejabberd.yml` file

```
api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      - access:
          - allow:
            - user: admin@host
      - oauth:
        - scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        - access:
          - allow:
            - user: admin@host
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      - ip: "127.0.0.1/8"
    what:
      - "status"
      - "connected_users_number"
commands_admin_access:
  - allow:
    - user: "admin@host"
commands:
  add_commands:
    - status
    - registered_users
    - register
    - unregister
    - get_roster
    - connected_users
    - send_stanza_c2s
    - send_stanza
    - join_cluster
    - send_direct_invitation
oauth_expire: 3600
oauth_access: all
```

I tried running this via command line and got this error

command: `ejabberdctl send_direct_invitation naviteam1519  conference.xxx.yyy.com "" "You need this room!" KESH2FABDE@xxx.yyy.com`

error:

```
Problem 'error {bad_jid,<<"KESH2FABDE@xxx.yyy.com">>}' occurred executing the command.
Stacktrace: [{jid,decode,1,[{file,"src/jid.erl"},{line,138}]},
         {mod_muc_admin,'-get_users_to_invite/2-fun-1-',2,
                        [{file,"src/mod_muc_admin.erl"},{line,840}]},
         {lists,filtermap,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1317}]},
         {mod_muc_admin,send_direct_invitation,5,
                        [{file,"src/mod_muc_admin.erl"},{line,826}]},
         {ejabberd_ctl,call_command,4,
                       [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,352}]},
         {ejabberd_ctl,try_call_command,4,
                       [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,321}]},
         {ejabberd_ctl,process2,4,
                       [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,271}]},
         {ejabberd_ctl,process,2,
                       [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,249}]}]
```

Comment: Need answer to take strategic move from this. ASAP reply may help my project moving forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show us your `ejabberdctl send_direct_invitation` command and  the logs.

My bet is that you don't have correctly formatted command:

from the [send_direct_invitation api](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#send-direct-invitation) it should look like this:

```
POST /api/send_direct_invitation
{
  "name": "room1",
  "service": "muc.example.com",
  "password": "",
  "reason": "Check this out!",
  "users": "user2@localhost:user3@example.com"
}
```

Then an example would look like this:

```
ejabberdctl send_direct_invitation aRoom conference.localhost "" "You need this room!" msg_test1@localhost
```

As for your `ejabbered.yml` file.  Are you sure you have:
`admin@host` user?  Shouldn't that be for you a `admin@localhost`?

**Edit**

Based on the comment: The OP is missing `mod-client-state` configuration
[mod-client-state](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#mod-client-state) configuration:

Example configuration:

```
modules:
  ...
  mod_client_state:
    queue_chat_states: true
    queue_pep: false
    queue_presence: true
  ...
```

Comment: Won't add stanza for kesh2fabde@xxx.yyy.com/s123123 to CSI queue

Comment: I have got response `0` and this message on logs `Won't add stanza for kesh2fabde@xxx.yyy.com/s123123 to CSI queu`
`Flushing packets of naviteam1519@conference.xxx.yyy.com from CSI queue of `

Comment: @ArpitVaishnav you are missing `mod_client_state` options.

Comment: I have added that , but no success. Any other option? It gives same error of `CSI queu`

Comment: what does `0` depict in api response

Comment: @ArpitVaishnav did you actually read the linked pages?  There you will find the information you are asking.  You are getting success, but `mod_client_state` is actually saving you bandwith and resources.

Comment: Have one piece of cake from my side.  Its done and dusted. Thank you so much. I needed to add him in to team as owner affiliation

Comment: @ArpitVaishnav as owner affiliation?  You mean MUC Room owner?   This link could help you https://www.ejabberd.im/node/4234/index.html.